# How to make a figure of 8 out of three cardioids

Tags: microphone-technique, field-recording

Hi,

I'm making a test setup for MS recording.

The 1st setup is with a figure 8 mic and a cardioid.
The 2nd setup is with a figure 8 mic and a omni.
The 3rd setup would be with 3 cardioids. (2 S channel placed exactly(!) opposite and phase aligned)

I found that by panning the two S cardioid mics hard left and right and adding M did not result in the same audio perception as with a figure 8 and cardioid.

What I did to resolve this:
First summing the two mics to make a new figure 8 signal.
1st S channel phase non inverted -> bus 1
2nd S channel phase inverted > bus 1

Then treat bus 1 (the 'new' figure 8 signal) as you would do normally with S signals
bus 1 > new channel 3 and pan hard left, phase non inverted
bus 1 > new channel 4 and pan hard right, phase inverted
channel 5 has the M signal.

This results in a much better MS with 3 cardioids.

Anyone agree/disagree?

Answer (score 1):

I went through this same process a while back when I realized that I couldn't afford a good fig 8 either.  I tried every setup in the book, but in the end you really do just need a good figure 8.  :)

You'll note that you're losing one of the primary MS benefits with this setup - the fig 8 mics wont cancel out when you sum to mono any more.  If anything summing to mono will *add* weirdness.  this is because you're now dealing with two capsules instead of one for that channel, and they're in slightly different physical spaces.

In the end I found that I much preferred the sound of just aiming the mics at in the different directions and calling it a day.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you basically made a complicated X/Y-setting. Two Cardioids together border/crosses over to Omni as they have a very wide pattern, whereas two Super Cardioids would get much closer to a true Figure-Of-8.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree that a true MS really needs a true fig 8, but as a test setup, or 'cheap' MS solution, the method in the OP could do the trick though.

Answer (score 0):

Your experiment is based on a false premise. A figure 8 mic picks up front and back 180 out of phase with the other, physically creating a perfect rejection zone to the sides. Just check out a figure 8 polar pattern.

2 cardiods back-to-back would need to be connected or mixed together with one out of phase with the other to emulate the figure 8 with the side rejection zone. Connecting or mixing 2 back-to-back cardiods in phase gives you a virtual omni, which is why it doesn't work in an M-S setup. Adding an inverted signal of the already-combined in-phase cardiods as you've done, is not the same - you just made 2 emulated omnis out of phase with each other, not a figure 8.

Here's the proper process - combine 2 cardiods back-to-back with the one pointing right flipped out-of-phase (if they're identical dynamics, you can get away with a y-cable with the right FE XLR pins 2&3 wired out of phase), designate that combined signal "L in-phase", pan L on mixer. Phase flip a duplicate of that combined L in-phase signal to generate a R out-of-phase, pan R on mixer. Add front facing cardiod panned center.

Even with the back-to-back cardiods combined out of phase with each other, because of the necessary physical spacing, they can never achieve as perfect a side signal rejection of a figure 8.

Further, many newer (I'm old) figure 8 mics use 2 capsules, each with its own diaphragm, and again due to physical spacing, though better than 2 out-of-phase cardiods, those still cannot achieve as perfect a side rejection of a ribbon figure 8, for which both front and back use the same diaphragm.

It's fine to emulate as best you can, and I sure have jerry-rigged setups when needed, but a ribbon figure 8 in an M-S setup is always the best way to go. Next choice, a 2-capsule figure 8.